# Unable to display my output as required . I'm trying to program a decimal to binary converter in x86 assembly language in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86, masm

This

[image: Screenshot]

is how my output should look like.

Here is my code:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
;Exit Process PROTO NEAR32 stdcall,dwExitCode:DWORD

INCLUDE io.h

cr EQU 0dh
Lf EQU 0ah

.STACK 4096


.DATA

prompt1 BYTE "Enter the decimal number: ", 0
asciiIn DW 4 DUP (?)

msgLabel BYTE "Result",00h; message Label
msgText BYTE "Your output" ;


          BYTE "Decimal: "
asciiDecimal DW 4 DUP (?),10

         BYTE "Binary: "
asciiBinary DW 4 DUP(?), 10   
         BYTE "Hex: "
asciiHex DW 4 DUP (?), 10     

decimal WORD 0
STR1 DW 4 DUP (?)
STR2 DW 4 DUP (?)


HEX      WORD 0


.CODE

_MainProc PROC
xor eax, eax    ; clear eax
xor ebx, ebx    ; clear ebx
xor ecx, ecx    ; clear ecx

lp : input prompt1, asciiIn, 10  ; prompt user to enter number
     atow   asciiIn   ; convert from ascii to word and store in eax

         LEA ESI,STR1
        ; MOV EAX,NO
         MOV BH,00
         MOV  BL,2
      L1:DIV  BL
         ADD AH,'0'
         MOV BYTE PTR[ESI],AH
         MOV AH,00
         INC ESI
         INC BH
         CMP AL,00
         JNE L1

         MOV CL,BH
         LEA ESI,STR1
         LEA EDI,STR2
         MOV CH,00
         ADD ESI,ECX
         DEC ESI

      L2:MOV AH,BYTE PTR[ESI]
         MOV BYTE PTR[EDI],AH
         DEC ESI
         INC EDI
         LOOP L2

    done : 

    ; output messages

      output  msgLabel,msgText
      wtoa asciiDecimal, asciiIn

      output asciiBinary,STR2
      wtoa asciiHex, HEX



    mov eax, 0
    ret

_MainProc ENDP
END
```

Comment: I still have to code decimal to hex. Any help for that also be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a debugging service, you need to pick up a debugger and invest a bit of time on it.

Comment: Why do you divide by `2`? Do you realize how the values in registers are encoded in the HW on the chip? In bits. `eax` **is** 32 bits. You just need to display `'1'` or `'0'` bit by bit from top most bit to lowest one. It's already converted into "binary" (by `atow` library function). There are instructions working with bits. For example `shl eax,1` will shift all bits up, with the 32nd bit going out into CF. If you would then use CF to adjust output char, and do this 32 times in a loop...

Comment: Anyway, `DIV  BL` does not work with `eax` and it will not produce what you expect. Don't guess or wish what an instruction does. Use Intel instruction reference guide or google to ALWAYS verify instructions you use, that you fully understand how they work. And start searching for debugger + learning how to use it, because you will get nowhere without it, from this initial try it doesn't look like you are talented enough to write asm without debugger.